# Base relative URL in Chrome & Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge

Sample directories and files:

```
parent/
├── images/
│   ├── cat.jpg
│   └── dog.jpg
└── demo.html
```

I use a relative URL in my demo file's `base` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Demo - Mori79</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <base href="images/">
</head>
<body>

<img src="cat.jpg" alt="Cat">
<img src="dog.jpg" alt="Dog">

</body>
</html>
```

And it works with no problem. But if you check the page source in Chrome & Edge, here's the destination the `base` relative URL points to: https://mori79.github.io/images/images/

**[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlzPH.jpg)**

It's different in Firefox & Safari: https://mori79.github.io/images/

Although the link text is the same, it points to different destinations in different browsers.

Here's a real **[demo](https://mori79.github.io/demo)**.

Is it my wrong coding? Or is it a bug in Chrome & Edge? Or probably in Firefox & Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a "bug" in the dev-tools, which is apparently reparsing the relative url, based on the value of the current `document.baseURI`.

Everything else works fine. You don't need to worry about this:

```js
console.log(document.baseURI, document.querySelector("base").href)
// logs correctly https://stacksnippets.net/foo/ twice
```

```html
<base href="foo/">
```

If you really want to you can open an issue at https://crbug.com but honestly this is so minor I doubt it's worth your time.

Comment: "That's just a 'bug' in the dev-tools" Actually, I see the same problem when I view the page source with **Ctrl+U**.

Comment: `view-source:` is still a "dev-tool". Your web page will work just fine.